# MySQL:How do you delete all old records of a specific user ID but keep the latest 3?

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called "tokens" that stores all of the login tokens for a user logged in to an admin panel.

```
    id  users_id    token   created_time        type        access_time
220 3       $....   2020-02-20 17:47:19 BACKOFFICE  2020-02-20 17:23:13
221 3       $....   2020-02-20 17:47:19 BACKOFFICE  2020-02-21 13:12:16
222 3       $....   2020-02-20 17:47:19 BACKOFFICE  2020-02-21 14:35:11
223 3       $....   2020-02-20 17:47:19 BACKOFFICE  2020-02-22 15:37:11
224 3       $....   2020-02-20 17:47:19 BACKOFFICE  2020-02-22 12:11:56
225 3       $....   2020-02-20 17:47:19 BACKOFFICE  2020-02-23 13:59:19
```

I store the users_id of the user, the time the token was created and any time the token is accessed and used (and some other bits)

My question is, how would I delete all of the reconds of a user, EXCEPT the latest 3 that were accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the latest 3 IDs, then exclude them when deleting.

```
DELETE tokens FROM tokens
LEFT JOIN (    
    SELECT id
    FROM tokens
    WHERE users_id = 3
    ORDER BY access_time DESC
    LIMIT 3) AS newest
ON tokens.id = newest.id
WHERE tokens.users_id = 3 AND newest.id IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e10dcd/1)

Comment: Forgot about that, I changed it to a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` and `join`:

```
delete t
    from tokens t join
         (select tt.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by access_time desc) as seqnum
          from tokens tt
         ) tt
         on tt.id = t.id
    where tt.seqnum > 3;
```